# Zoom in osmdroid and reload tiles

Tags: android, android-mapview, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I`m using osmdroid 4.0. When I change zoom with using multi touch, tiles reloading only when touch up.
How can I reload tiles before touch up happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that as you pinch-to-zoom that the tiles only reload once you remove your fingers from the screen? This is the expected behavior and is the same as previous versions.

If you want it to reload tiles in the middle of a pinch-to-zoom then you can open a feature request on the [issues](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/list) page or submit a patch. This would be a nice feature and is probably quite do-able.